# Populating Select Field from Database

Tags: php, database, loops, select, echo

I'm trying to populate a `select` field with PHP.  The problem is I can't figure out how to display them because I'm getting the one that's value matches in the database showing up twice because I'm echoing it as selected and then looping it all the results. How can I just display the `selected` one that matched the fields value and then all the ones that don't match the selected one?

**TABLE CATEGORIES**

```
cat_id  cat_name
1       soccer
2       baseball
3       basketball
```

**TABLE ARTICLES**

```
art_id art_cat_id
1      1
```

**PHP / HTML**

```
<select name="category">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT cat_id cat_name, art_id, art_cat_id 
            FROM categories LEFT JOIN articles
            ON categories.cat_id = articles.art_cat_id
            WHERE art_id = 1";
    $result = query($sql);

    if($result===false) {
        echo("Query Fail");
    }
    else {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data['art_cat_id'] ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $data['cat_name'] ?></option>
        <?php
        while( $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        ?>     
        <option value="<?php echo $data['cat_id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['cat_name'] ?></option>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

**What it's returning**

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">soccer</option>
    <option value="1">soccer</option>
    <option value="2">baseball</option>
    <option value="3">basketball</option>
</select>
```

**What I'm looking for**

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">soccer</option>
    <option value="2">baseball</option>
    <option value="3">basketball</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 for organizing your question very well :)

Comment: I can see that you printed first option before starting while loop, but how the data printed for first one?! because it not available yet

Comment: Thanks :), and sorry I have a sql statement before that which is populating other fields and I'm just getting the `art_cat_id` and `cat_name` with that statement and then looping for the rest. I hope that makes sense.. `art_cat_id` and the first `cat_name` are actually using `$row['art_cat_id']` and `$row['cat_name']` then I do the second sql and I'm using `$data['cat_id']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip the row if the value matches the first one.

A snippet:

```
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $data['art_cat_id'] ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $data['cat_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    while( $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($data['art_cat_id'] == $data['cat_id']) continue;
    ?>     
    <option value="<?php echo $data['cat_id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['cat_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate you're time!