# How do I populate form fields on a page from a database based on the page url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, database

Hello first I’d like to say, please excuse my ignorance to this all, as I’m very new to this all.  I just started and still trying to understand this.

So far I have a database set up and I’m trying to retrieve values from a database to fill in a form on a page when it loads.  The record or row/values that need to be retrieved from a database depend on the page’s URL.

I’m ok with html and css but still trying to learn more about jquery, JavaScript, sql, php and so on and so forth.  I realize I have a ways to go and honestly some of the guides and tutorials online are kind of confusing because everyone has a different way of coding.  So I’m a bit confused.

I’ve included a simple chart to breakdown what I’m trying to do.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezMBm.png]

If someone could point me in the right direction I’d be really grateful! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some way to tell witch keys need to be associated with witch page?

Comment: A similar one,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733454/populating-select-field-from-database

Comment: I dont thats why im trying to go by the page url if thats even possible

Comment: Well, how do **you** know, what data should be put there?

Comment: i guess thats what I'm trying to really figure out

Comment: When you find out, what data should go to what page, then add an extra id field in your database ( like page ID or something ) and after that you can fetch the fields by the received id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want to setup a form and populate some fields of this form with a query forms a database, the primary key of the record being relative to the url.

The first step is to build the url, you can pass some parameters to an url by adding a `?` at the end of the url followed by the parameter name, the `=` sign and the parameter value. If you have more than one parameter, you should separate each parameter with the sign `&`.

So your url could be something like this :
`www.examplesite.com/page&.html?key=key_A1`

Then, you'll have to choose if you want to build the page on the server side with a language like [php](/questions/tagged/php), in which case you retrieve the parameter, query the database, build the html form and send it to the client.

You can also go client side with plain [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), in which case you will still have to do some server side programming to query the database but will use an ajax call to get the data and will populate the fields in Javascript or JQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using Javscript(using Ajax)

1. U need the key to search for get the results from database
2. Using ajax call get the data, You might have to write code to get the details from database  using any server side prog language
3. Using javascript to fill the form input with the received data.

Google for jquery ajax examples, and how to populate input using javascript.

There are many frameworks out there that have DataBinding built-in that do the same job a lot easier.  My favourite would be Angular Js, you can try Ember and lot more out there, choose the one you feel comfortable with.